# Implementing Logistic Regression with Scipy: Why does this Scipy optimization return all zeros?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, numerical-methods

I am trying to implement a one versus many logistic regression as in Andrew Ng's [machine learning class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/week/5), He uses an octave function called `fmincg` in his implementation.  I have tried to use several functions in the [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/optimize.html), but I keep getting all zeros in the classifier output, no matter what I put in.

In the last many hours, I've checkout out a ton of resources, but the most helpful have been [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801002/fminunc-alternate-in-numpy), and [this blog post](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2011/11/machine-learning-with-python-logistic.html).

Is there any obvious or not so obvious place where my implementation has gone astray?

```
import scipy.optimize as op

def sigmoid(z):
    """takes matrix and returns result of passing through sigmoid function"""
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))

def lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lam=0):
    """
    evaluates logistic regression cost function:

    theta: coefficients. (n x 1 array)
    X: data matrix (m x n array)
    y: ground truth matrix (m x 1 array)
    lam: regularization constant
    """
    m = len(y)
    theta = theta.reshape((-1,1))
    theta = np.nan_to_num(theta)

    hypothesis = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    term1 = np.dot(-y.T,np.log(hypothesis))
    term2 = np.dot(1-y.T,np.log(1-hypothesis))
    J = (1/m) * term1 - term2
    J = J + (lam/(2*m))*np.sum(theta[1:]**2)
    return J

def Gradient(theta, X, y, lam=0):
    m = len(y)
    theta = theta.reshape((-1,1))
    hypothesis = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))
    residuals = hypothesis - y 
    reg = theta  
    reg[0,:] = 0
    reg[1:,:] = (lam/m)*theta[1:]
    grad = (1.0/m)*np.dot(X.T,residuals)
    grad = grad + reg
    return grad.flatten()

def trainOneVersusAll(X, y, labels, lam=0):
    """
    trains one vs all logistic regression.

    inputs:
        - X and Y should ndarrays with a row for each item in the training set
        - labels is a list of labels to generate probabilities for.
        - lam is a regularization constant

    outputs:
        - "all_theta", shape = (len(labels), n + 1) 
    """
    y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
    m, n = np.shape(X)
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((m, 1)), X))
    all_theta = np.zeros((len(labels), n + 1))
    for i,c in enumerate(labels):
        initial_theta = np.zeros(n+1)
        result, _, _ = op.fmin_tnc(func=lrCostFunction, 
                            fprime=Gradient,
                            x0=initial_theta, 
                            args=(X, y==c, lam))
        print result
        all_theta[i,:] = result
    return all_theta


def predictOneVsAll(all_theta, X):
    pass

a = np.array([[ 5.,  5.,  6.],[ 6.,  0.,  8.],[ 1.,  1.,  1.], [ 6.,  1.,  9.]])
k = np.array([1,1,0,0])
# a = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])
# k = np.array([0,1])
solution = np.linalg.lstsq(a,k)
print 'x', solution[0]
print 'resid', solution[1]
thetas = trainOneVersusAll(a, k, np.unique(k))
```

Comment: Did you try to start optimization from random vector instead of np.zeros?

Comment: No, I didn't try that...

Comment: okay. Just tried it.  No luck...

Comment: Your code shows that you are using `fmin_tnc`.  It has three return values, but you are ignoring two of them.  If you are going to debug this problem, you should certainly be checking all the return values, especially the third, which is the return code.  See the docstring for its interpretation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc.html

Comment: the third variable was returning 2s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `Gradient` function. In `numpy` assignment is **not copying objects**, so your line

```
reg = theta
```

makes `reg` a reference to `theta`, so each time you compute gradient you actually modify your current solution. It should be

```
reg = theta.copy()
```

I would also suggest starting from random weights

```
initial_theta = np.random.randn(n+1)
```

Now solution is no longer zeros (although I did not check each formula, so there still might be mathematical error). It is also worth noting, that for linearly separable problems, logistic regression without regularization is ill-posed (its objective is unbounded), so I suggest testing with `lam>0`.