# SciPy minimize with gradient

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimization

This is an implementation of logistic regression, using a toy data set. Some feedback from [@dermen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077270/dermen) helped me fix a basic problem with how I was using `scipy.optimize.minimize` but even after fixing that issue, optimize fails to converge, even just using the first five rows of the test data set. Here is a stand-along version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# `data` is a subset of a toy dataset. The full dataset is ~100 rows, linearly seperable and located at 
# https://github.com/liavkoren/ng-redux/blob/master/ex2/ex2data1.txt
data = np.array([
    [ 34.62365962, 78.02469282],
    [ 30.28671077, 43.89499752],
    [ 35.84740877, 72.90219803],
    [ 60.18259939, 86.3085521 ],
    [ 79.03273605, 75.34437644],
    [ 45.08327748, 56.31637178],
    [ 61.10666454, 96.51142588],
    [ 75.02474557, 46.55401354],
    [ 76.0987867,  87.42056972],
    [ 84.43281996, 43.53339331],
])
# Ground truth
y = np.array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.])


def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.power(np.e, -z))

h = lambda theta, x: sigmoid(x.dot(theta))


def cost(theta, X, y):
    m = X.shape[0]
    j = y.dot(np.log(h(theta, X)))  + (1 - y).dot(np.log(1 - h(theta, X)))
    return (-j/m)


def grad(theta, X, y):
    m = X.shape[0]
    return ((h(theta, X) - y).dot(X))/m

# Add a column of ones:
m, features = np.shape(X_initial)
features += 1
X = np.concatenate([np.ones((m, 1)), X_initial], axis=1)
initial_theta = np.zeros((features))


def check_functions(grad_func, cost_func):
    '''
    Asserts that the cost and gradient functions return known corret values for a given theta, X, y.  
    Test case from https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/discussions/weeks/3/threads/tA3ESpq0EeW70BJZtLVfGQ
    The expected cost is 4.6832.
    The expected gradient = [0.31722, 0.87232, 1.64812, 2.23787]
    '''
    test_X = np.array([[1, 8, 1, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 9, 2]])  # X
    test_y = np.array([[1, 0, 1]])  # y
    test_theta = np.array([-2, -1, 1, 2])

    grad_diff = grad_func(test_theta, test_X, test_y) - np.array([0.31722, 0.87232, 1.64812, 2.23787])
    assert grad_diff.dot(grad_diff.T) < 0.0001
    assert abs(cost_func(test_theta, test_X, test_y, debug=False) - 4.6832) < 0.0001

check_functions(grad, cost)

# `cutoff` slices out a subset of rows.
cutoff = 2
print minimize(fun=cost, x0=initial_theta, args=(X[0:cutoff, :], y[0:cutoff]), jac=grad)
```

This code fails with:

```
   fun: nan
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 32
      nit: 1
     njev: 32
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([ -0.5       , -16.2275926 , -30.47992258])

/Users/liavkoren/Envs/data-sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:25: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
/Users/liavkoren/Envs/data-sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:38: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
/Users/liavkoren/Envs/data-sci/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:42: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

Comment: can you try calling minimize like this:  ```minimize(curried_cost, initial_theta.T, jac=curried_grad)``` i.e. transposing ```initial_theta```.  Also the main point of this question is how to call minimize, so I would advise removing all the stuff about the machine learning class (which can't even be linked to) and simply create some test variables and apply them to the minimize function to test it's usage.

Comment: @dermen: same ValueError when calling with `initial_theta.T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was overflow occurring in the calls to `np.power` inside the `sigma` function. I added debugging messages into the `cost` function and saw the following:

```
theta: [ 0.  0.  0.]
--
X: [[  1.          34.62365962  78.02469282]
 [  1.          30.28671077  43.89499752]]
--
y=1: [ 0.5  0.5]  y=0: [ 0.5  0.5]
log probabilities: 
y=1: [-0.69314718 -0.69314718]
y=0: [-0.69314718 -0.69314718]
=======

theta: [ -0.5        -16.2275926  -30.47992258]
--
X: [[  1.          34.62365962  78.02469282]
 [  1.          30.28671077  43.89499752]]
--
y=1: [ 0.  0.]  y=0: [ 1.  1.]
log probabilities: 
y=1: [-inf -inf]
y=0: [ 0.  0.]
```

This overflows on the second iteration!!

I quickly confirmed that this does seem to be to problem by dividing the dataset by 1/10 and it converged. I guess I will have to look at feature scaling/normalization or some other strategies for avoiding overflow.