# fminunc alternate in Math.NET Numerics(C# )

Tags: c#, machine-learning, octave, mathnet-numerics

Is there an alternative to the fminunc function (from octave/matlab) in Math.NET Numerics?

[python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801002/fminunc-alternate-in-numpy)

this is an answer for python. Is there any function in Math.NET Numerics?

**fminunc**:"Conjugate gradient", "BFGS", and "L-BFGS"

no need to give learning rate and iterations  with it

it faster Gradient Descent but more sophisticated

it supply by Octave/Matlab

Comment: Any comment on what `fminunc` does?

Comment: @Abion47 add some comments above

Comment: There is an alternative implementation in development, but it has not yet been merged into the main branch and thus not released yet. We'd be very interested in how it works for you though, if building from the source is an option.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg  thanks. Really looking forward to released.